# Find records with same value in different column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I have a table called redirects which has columns `from_url` and `to_url`.

They are used to redirect users from one url to another.

So for example I might have:

```
id: 1
from_url: /about-us
to_url: /about
```

However I want to prevent infinite loops should the same redirect be created the other way-around (as these are generated when a user changes the url for a page in the CMS, so could change it back to its original value).

So for example:

```
id: 1
from_url: /about-us
to_url: /about

id: 2
from_url: /about
to_url: /about-us
```

In this scenario, I'd want to remove the first record as we've superseded it with a new redirect to catch the change and the original redirect is the now the correct url again.

In my model I have method called `test_and_clean`

```
def self.test_and_clean
  redirects = Redirect.all
  conflicts = []
  redirects.each do |redirect|
    redirects.each do |redirect2|
      # if from_url has a matching to_url (causing a loop)
      if redirect.from_url == redirect2.to_url
        conflicts.push(redirect2)
      end
    end
  end
  # destroy all the conflicts
  conflicts.each do |conflict|
    conflict.destroy
  end
end
```

Aside from nesting the loops being rather nasty, their is an issue with this approach, the initial loop will find both redirects because the `from_url` and `to_url` will match on both redirects, so both will be deleted. How can I make it so that it only deletes the latter? I don't want to rely on any `last` methods, as that might not be guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

The following implementation doesn't use nested loop, but does use a nested DB query to find out the conflicts (I hope you do this in a background job or something).

```
def self.test_and_clean
  conflicts = []

  # Find all the conflicts
  Redirect.find_each do |redirect|
    # Check if the current redirect was already detected as conflict
    unless conflicts.include?(redirect)
      conflict = Redirect.find_by(from_url: redirect.to_url, to_url: redirect.from_url)
      conflicts.push(conflict) unless conflict.nil?
    end
  end

  # destroy all the conflicts
  conflicts.each do |conflict|
    conflict.destroy
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inner join redirects table on itself with your conditions as following:

```
SELECT r1.id, r2.id FROM redirects r1
INNER JOIN redirects r2 ON r1.from_url = r2.to_url 
AND r1.to_url = r2.from_url 
AND r1.id != r2.id
```

Arel form would be something as following:

```
Redirects.joins("inner join #{Redirect.table_name} as r2 ON 
#{Redirect.table_name}.from_url = r2.to_url 
AND #{Redirect.table_name}.to_url = r2.from_url 
AND #{Redirect.table_name}.id != r2.id").pluck('redirects.id', 'r2.id')
```

This should return an array of pairs of ids. From each collect the largest id and delete those rows

```
Redirect.delete((pairs.collect {|pair| pair.sort.last}).uniq)
```

But ideally for your case this should have been a validation before save to verify if there are any records forming infinite loop.